# 3-level Hierarchical SQL Query

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle, treeview, hierarchical

I'm very well aware of basic SQL queries, however I've never worked with a query that deals with hierarchical data.

I'm using the Telerik TreeView control to display data related to a school board with the following structure:

```
--School "ABC"
----Class "Grade 1"
----Class "Grade 2"
------Student #1
------Student #2
--School "DEF"
----Class "Grade 1"
------Student #3
----Class "Grade 3"
```

The TreeView is in a tri-state checkbox mode, so each element can be checked off. So if a single child element is checked then the parent element will be checked as well, and when checking a parent element all the child elements will be checked.

After checking off some schools, classes, and students, the following screen displays information about the students in a graph which currently uses the school IDs (if multiple are checked) to select all students of those schools.

Here's where it gets tricky. Using the above structure as an example, I select the class "Grade 1" from the school "ABC" and class "Grade 3" from the school "DEF" which in turn will select the students #1 & #2 AND the schools "ABC" & "DEF".

> Selected schools: ABC, DEF
>
> Selected classes: Grade 1, Grade 3
>
> Selected Students: #1, #2

As mentioned before, my current SQL query is based solely on the school ID and I know that I can't simply add two other conditions in the where clause that look like this:

```
AND ClassID IN ('Grade 1', 'Grade 3') --Note there is no primary key for classes, and I can't change that in my position..
AND StudentID IN (1,2)
```

as this will also select student #3 from the other class title "Grade 1"

So my question is, how to I combine the School ID(s), Class name(s), and student ID(s) into one condition that will solve this issue.

**Edit:**

Here's a structure of the tables.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking to write a SQL query that will return all classes based on a list of schools, and all students based on a list of classes? You cannot have a `SELECT` that will return all children, since classes and students are of different tables.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you have the selected school, class and student. So would this work for you:

```
where (school = "ABC" and 
        class = "Grade1") 
   OR
      (school = "DEF" and 
        class = "Grade3")
```

I hope i understood your requirements correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately it has to be dynamic. There are 64 schools in the school board (with over 1000 classes) and depending on who is accessing the system, only certain schools, classes and students will be visible to that user.

Comment: Okay i get it, can you please edit your question with the table structure you are using. Sounds like you are going to need the CONNECT BY clause for this.